# Offline updates for freshly installed Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: updates, ubuntu-10.04

I've just made a fresh installation of Ubuntu 10.04 on my Dell Inspiron 1420. Without updates, I'm not able to play media files. Is there any procedure to install updates via offline as I don't have a internet connection at home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to download all packages and dependencies manually.

Start Synaptic on your offline-computer, mark the desired packages for installation and then choose "File" -> "Generate Package download list". 
This will get you a shell-script with several lines of "wget fooBar" which you can run on your online-computer. Put all downloaded packages in one folder on the offline-pc and then run "sudo dpkg -i *.deb"

Answer (score 2):

Hmm using Linux without an internet connection will give you a headache (or two..three).

Fetching all the packages for restricted playback..phew.. quite a job.
http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse
http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse

You have to also get the missing deps listed on the page. Not an easy task. :P

---

How to install them after you downloaded them? Put them ALL in one folder and do:
`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
If it says something is missing, you have to fetch it. As I said, you should really get some internet if you want to use a linux distro.

Answer (score 1):

NO;you don't need to have internet connection to use linux distro like ubuntu. Use keryx this will take care every thing.

Comment: http://keryxproject.org/